# How and Why to Create a webservice?

Tags: asp.net, web-services

I have a small routine that programmatically builds an XML file that resides in memory based on a dataset that I send to the routine (it's called CreateAdXML()).

My buddy says I should turn it into a 'webservice', but I'm not quite sure what he means or how to do that.  Can someone offer me some pointers?  Is it relatively easy to take existing code for an asp.net site and turn it into a webservice?

Comment: Well, Web Service is a quite generic term. What kind of "client" would consume this webservice ?

Comment: Agreed. If no client will consume it, then you don't need a web service. If you _do_ need a web service, then you should be sure to use WCF or maybe the new ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possibilities to create web services for an ASP.NET application. It all comes down to what you actually need:

If you need secure connections, advanced serialization, WSDL support etc...

- Go for WCF (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Communication_Foundation)
- MSDN : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms735119(v=vs.90).aspx

If you only to expose a few methods:

- Go for WebMethods (that's **deprecated** + **quick and dirty** in my opinion)
- WebMethod tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/byxd99hx(v=vs.90).aspx

If you need to expose data through a standardized interface, interoperable and bandwith-friendly service (that's called REST):

- Go for Web APIs
- Official page: http://www.asp.net/web-api

There also a lot of webservices frameworks available on codeplex, do some research to see if one suits your need better. A few well known are RestSharp and ServiceStack.

**My advice:**
From what you described, I would go with WebMethods for test purposes only. Once you know more about the client that will consume you web service, chose one of the apropriate framework.
If however you need to expose more methods, you should consider using Web APIs or WCF from the start, since these are much cleaner web service frameworks. It will also make you service stack MUCH easier to maintain.

Comment: -1: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: Didn't know asmx had been deprecated officially, will update the post. Thanks.

Comment: Better, but did you realize that `WebMethod` implies ASMX?

Comment: Yes, but if he only needs to expose a single method without adding a whole WCF stack to his infrastructure, deployement etc ... It would be a "quick and dirty" solution. Edited again.

Comment: "The whole WCF stack" has become much simpler since .NET 4.0. Also, using a `WebMethod` brings in "the whole ASMX stack", which, as I said, should not be used for new development.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me more like you need to make it a utility method instead of a web service, as this will allow all of your web project to use this functionality, but not necessarily expose it beyond the boundaries of your application.

If you insist on making it a web service, then read [A Beginner's Tutorial for Understanding Windows Communication Foundation (WCF)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/406096/A-beginners-tutorial-for-understanding-Windows).

Answer (score 0):

It is fairly easy to create web services from ASP.NET code (VB.NET/C# etc..)

You can use the following link to help you understand more about ASP.NET Web Services.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: -1: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: I'm sorry, where have I mentioned `ASMX`?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, I've just noticed the notice at the top of the link I posted.

Answer (score 0):

[HOW TO: Write a Simple Web Service by Using Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308359)

But all of the other answers are good too.

Comment: -1: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.